# ffmpeg -movflags +faststart in clipbucket video script

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, libx264, clipbucket

i am a little new at `ffmpeg`.

Have a video script ( ClipBucket ) and would like to know how to add `-movflags +faststart` to the script to take advantage of this for `.mp4` videos being converted.

here is the code `ffmpeg.class.php`. Not sure where I can add this to work properly

https://github.com/arslancb/clipbucket/tree/master/upload/includes/classes/conversion

> ffmpeg.class.php and conversion.class.php

Seems to be the correct file(s), just not sure where to add it

Thanks so much in advance.

Spiro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should alter the file format assignments wherever they occur:

```
    # file format
    if(isset($p['format']))
        $opt_av .= " -movflags +faststart -f {$p['format']} ";
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, just one quick question, how to verify that this is working ? is there a way via ssh using ffmpeg ?? to see if it worked for all new videos I upload. I have altered all areas that have the code above.

Comment: Check the first 72 bytes of the output and see if the string `moov` is found.

Comment: 645.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=6 speed=0.901x frame= 186 fps= 24 q=28.0 size= 541kB time=00:00:07.17 bitrate= 618.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=6 speed=0.912x [mp4 @ 0x23fd580] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame= 194 fps= 23 q=-1.0 Lsize= 564kB time=00:00:08.30 bitrate= 556.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=7 speed=0.964x 
video:561kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.533687%